# mongodb-org unable to locate package

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

im following a simple guide to install mongodb-org on ubuntu 18.04 LTS but i always receive this error

**E: unable to locate package mongodb-org**

I use these commands

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

final result is this

[image]
My OS is running on a simple droplet on Digital Ocean. i have tried literally any online guide, final result is always the same.
I dont want to install standard mongodb because i need the 4.x version

Comment: Please don't post screenshot for text. It's very hard to read and not searchable. Please copy the content of that screenshot as text and replace the screenshot.

Comment: In your screenshot you are adding the Debian Stretch packages rather than the Ubuntu Bionic one listed in your commands: `echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list`. Try adding the correct repo. The output of`apt-get update` should indicate that package information is being fetched from `repo.mongodb.org`.

Comment: i solved was a problem with the character "pipe". thank you all guys